# How to make Camera Image blank on Linux Fedora While used

Tags: fedora, camera

Hello this is probably crazy question, my aim is to disable the video capture after I press a button and run script, and it already works, the problem is it only works when the camera isn't used. If the camera is used, then it's failed to turn off (error device is in use). Any suggestion or workaround is really appreciated. Thank you!

This is my code

```bash
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(grep "uvcvideo" /proc/modules | wc -l)
if [ $STATUS -gt 0 ]
then
   /usr/sbin/rmmod -f uvcvideo
   sudo -u ben DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "Disabling Camera" "The Camera just disabled!" -a Camera -e -t 2000 -i camera-web
else
   /usr/sbin/modprobe uvcvideo
   sudo -u ben DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "Enabling Camera" "The Camera just enabled!" -a Camera -e -t 2000 -i camera-web
fi
```